# Getting specific charts from array in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble getting specific charts from a spreadsheet using an array. The code below is an extract of a function that sends an email which includes charts:

```
var sheetSummary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
var charts = sheetSummary.getCharts();
var chartBlobs = new Array(charts.length);
var emailImages = {};
for(var i=0; i < charts.length; i++){
  chartBlobs[i] = charts[i].getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob"+i);
  var emailChart = "<img src='cid:chart" + i + "'> test<br> "
  emailImages["chart"+i] = chartBlobs[i]
  }
```

The only values of chartBlobs in the final line of this extract that sends an image of a chart in the email are

`chartBlobs[i]`

and

`chartBlobs[0]`

even though there are 4 charts [0,1,2,3] in the charts.length array and on the sheet.

How can I change this to send e.g. chart [2] or [3], and how can I change this to send e.g. chart [2] and [3] together as two separate images in the email?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an email with the inline images.
- You want to use the images by giving the index of chart.

  - As a sample, you want to use the index of `1` and `2` from `[0,1,2,3]` of the retrieved charts.

#### Modification points:

- In this answer, at first, `var chartIndex = [2, 3];` is declared for retrieving the charts by the index. From your question, in this sample, 2 and 3 are used.
- In this case, I think that `emailChart` is required to be added `"<img src='cid:chart" + i + "'> test<br> "` for each image.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set the index of chart you want to use to `var chartIndex = [2, 3];`.

```
var chartIndex = [2, 3]; // Please set the index of chart. Here, from your question, 2 and 3 are used.
var sheetSummary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
var charts = sheetSummary.getCharts();
var emailImages = {};
var emailChart = "";
chartIndex.forEach(i => {
  emailChart += "<img src='cid:chart" + i + "'> test<br> ";
  emailImages["chart" + i] = charts[i].getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob" + i);
});

// This is a sample for sending the email with the inline images.
MailApp.sendEmail({to: '###', subject: '###', htmlBody: emailChart, inlineImages: emailImages});
```

- In this script, when `var chartIndex = [2, 3];` is modified to `var chartIndex = [2];`, the chart of the index `2` is used.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response! To achieve the same result as your code I could just do something like the code below. What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to select a specific chart from i at the end of the code, rather than the start by predefining the chart I want through chartIndex.

  (`var charts = sheetSummary.getCharts()[0].getAs("image/png");
  var emailChart = "tes <img src='cid:chart" + 1 + "'>"
  emailImages["chart"+1] = charts;')`)

Also your code gives this error when I tried it: Exception: Converting from image/png to image/png. is not supported. google script.

Comment: @George Bates Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to select a specific chart from i at the end of the code, rather than the start by predefining the chart I want through chartIndex.`. Especially, I cannot understand about `select a specific chart from i`. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @George Bates And, I cannot replicate your issue of `Exception: Converting from image/png to image/png`. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you add your current script for replicating it to your question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Your English is great! I've managed to get it to work now thanks.

Comment: @George Bates Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.